# nginx "deny all" location not working when clicking href-element

Tags: linux, nginx, reverse-proxy, web

I'm trying to deny acess to the root url of a proxied web application. Only the path `/images` is supposed to be accessible from the internet.

My nginx configuration for the page looks like this:

```
...
server {
        location / {
                deny all;
        }
        location /images {
                proxy_pass https://xyz.abc/images;

}
...
```

However, if i click a button with `href="/"` on the `/images` page, i can access the `/`-site. When i refresh this page now, i get a 403 error. But this only happens after the refresh, not when first clicking the `href="/"` button.

Thank you!

Comment: Try with browser cache disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [@drookie](https://serverfault.com/users/165991/drookie), disabling browser cache solved the problem. I tried on another computer and it worked!